# E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION, Viewpager Android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

while I test my android app, I get the follow error in the Android-Studio-Console:

```
04-30 17:06:19.811    2431-2431/com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila, PID: 2431
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila.Frag1.onCreateView(Frag1.java:12)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1072)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:918)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1440)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila.Frag1.onCreateView(Frag1.java:12)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1072)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:918)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1440)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 144000012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 54MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapF
```

I have 2 classes in my project and 3 fragments classes

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    }

}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    //TAB TITLES
    private String tabtitles[]=new String[] {"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"};
    Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();
                return frag1;
            case 1:
                Frag2 frag2 = new Frag2();
                return frag2;

            case 2:
                Frag3 frag3 = new Frag3();
                return frag3;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabtitles[position];
    }
}
```

The app also works with the error, but it is not nice to have an error in one app. I already googled a lot but my java skills are not enough very far and this is my first self-created app

Comment: Post the XML. The exception says it is in the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to load an image that will take 144000012 bytes (137MB) as part of inflating some layout file. You do not have that much heap space. Please use a smaller image -- the one you are using is **huge** (6000x6000 pixels or thereabouts).

Comment: Great, Thank you one more question the larger image i have is 2000 px, here is the xml layout code

Comment: Please help me my friend with this question     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980377/fix-viewpager-android-views