# Fix Viewpager Android Views

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have Android application with a tabbed viewpager see the image screenshot of the running app

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhlKF.png

The problem is that i see blank pages instead my xml layout referenced with fragment classes, 
What is the correct way to write the XML file to be supported by the Viewpager
Here is the XML Layout code
first1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="HOLA MUNDO"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Frag1.java

```
package com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first1, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Frag2.java

```
package com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Frag2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first2, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Frag3.java

```
package com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Frag3 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first3, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is the Main Activity code
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    }

}
```

And ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.aliencomputing.kakamila;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    //TAB TITLES
    private String tabtitles[]=new String[] {"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"};
    Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();
                return frag1;
            case 1:
                Frag2 frag2 = new Frag2();
                return frag2;

            case 2:
                Frag3 frag3 = new Frag3();
                return frag3;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabtitles[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `R.layout.activity_main` look? Can you post it?

Comment: Here is the activity_main.xml                                                                           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

Comment: Please edit it as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the activity_main you posted: you need a viewgroup outside of the viewpager, and you need to make the height of pagertabstrip wrap content.

the java code you posted looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong `activity_main` layout, so try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
  xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:id="@+id/pager" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

  <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_gravity="top"
      /> 

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

main mistake in your original is: `android:layout_height="match_parent"`